# Finite element method how to implement neumann boundary condition with implicit method

Tags: finite-element-method

I have implemented a finite element method to solve the 1D heat conduction equation:

$$
\frac{\partial T(x,t)}{\partial t} = k\frac{\partial^2T(x,t)}{\partial x^2}
$$

This is done using an implicit method by solving the set of equations:

$$
-sT^{n+1}_{i+1} -(1+2s)T^{n+1}_{i} -sT^{n+1}_{i-1} = T^n_i
$$

with $n$ the steps in time and $i$ the steps in the $x$ direction.

This can be represented by the following matrix equation: 
$$
Ax=b
$$

with (with a simple system of 4 steps in length):
$$
A= \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0& 0 & 0  \\
   -s      & (1+2s) & -s & 0  \\
   0     &  -s & (1+2s) & -s \\
   0     & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
x= \begin{bmatrix}
  T^{n+1}_1      \\
  T^{n+1}_2     \\
  T^{n+1}_3  \\
  T^{n+1}_4  
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
B= \begin{bmatrix}
  T^{n}_1      \\
  T^{n}_2     \\
  T^{n}_3  \\
  T^{n}_4  
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If I want fixed temperature on the surface all I have to do is set $T^{n}_1 = T_{surf}$.

Now the question is what if I want to not have a fixed temperature but a heat flux into the surface:

$$
\frac{\partial T(x=0,t)}{\partial x} = c1
$$

Is it simply changing my vector $b$ by setting $T^{n}_1 = T^{n-1}_1+c1$ and not changing the matrix $A$?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: I think your system matrix also needs to be changed as well - I would double check but I don't have my class notes with me now.

Comment: Its what I thought initially, from what I gather it changes the first equation of the set to $(1+2s) T^{n+1}_1-2s T^{n+1}_2 =  T^{n}_1-2s\Delta xc_1$. This would then change $A[1,1] = 1+2s $ and $A[0,1] = -s $ but If I do this python tells me I am trying to solve a singular matrix>